# Preto installation /setup failed

Tags: presto

I have configured presto on master and slave nodes . Ghe queries are running fine on both the master and slave seperately.
But in UI it only shows 1 active worker

Tried to set up presto on master and slave but unable to cordinate between them

Comment: Can you attach the server.log to your question?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what the issue might be without seeing your configuration details. Perhaps you have not set `node-scheduler.include-coordinator=true`? This property, when set to true, indicates that you want work to be scheduled on the coordinator node as well.

Comment: Master config.properties
coordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=false
http-server.http.port=8080
query.max-memory=10GB
query.max-memory-per-node=1GB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=http://172.*.*.*:8080/


worker node=coordinator=false
http-server.http.port=8080
query.max-memory=10GB
query.max-memory-per-node=1GB
discovery.uri=http://172.*.*.*:8080/

Comment: @tusharbhatia thanks for supplying the config! Since it looks like you have `node-scheduler.include-coordinator=false`, try setting that to true instead in order to see both of the nodes doing work on a query